# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'getAttribute'

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

```
ppListView = $("#listPProfiles").kendoMobileListView({
    dataSource: this.data(),
    selectable: true,
    change: onChange,
    template: kendo.template($("#templatePPListItem").html())
});
```

This is the code, where I am getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'getAttribute'`.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: please share the code of the template. From the error it seems that you are not passing the correct object to the template